# Linethrough/Strikethrough to a row if a column contains specific text using SQL

Tags: php, sql

I need to add a strikethrough to some rows that contain the word "old" in the 'notes' column.
I'm using php code connected to sql database.
Is there any example code on how to do that?

This is the current code I'm using:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".$mysqli->error);

mysqli_select_db($con, 'mysql') or die(mysqli_error($con));
$result= $con->query("SELECT * FROM `cloud_team` WHERE `Vendor` = 'cisco' ORDER BY `customer_name` DESC") or die($mysqli->error);;

echo "<table align='center' border='3' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>";

echo "<thead><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>customer number</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>customer name</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>Platform</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>MGMT IP</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>Current Version</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>Recommended Version</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>Last Version</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>GUI User</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>Serial</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>date</th><th style='background-color:#00ffff'>Notes</th></thead>";

$i=1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

if($i%2==0)
{
    echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFF00">';
}
else
{
    echo '<tr bgcolor="#99FFCC">';
}
    $i++;

echo "<a ='send.php'>" . "<td> " . $row['customer_number'] . "<td> " . $row['customer_name'] . "<td> " . $row['Platform'] . " <td> " . $row['MGMT_IP'] . " <td> " . $row['Version'] . " <td> " . $row['recommended_version'] . " <td> " . $row['last_version'] . " <td> " . $row['GUI_User'] . "<td> " . $row['serial'] . "<td> "  . $row['Service_contract'] . "<td> " .$row['Notes']. "</a></td>";

echo "<td><a href='/cloudpass/viewpass.php?id=".$row['ID']."' target=\"_blank\"  class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>View Password</a></td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$con->close;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What code have you written and where are you having problems?

Comment: I just want to add somekthing new to the code . there is not problem :)
I need a sample of code that is doing the following:
if you find the word "Old" in the column "Notes" , then add a strikethrough to the row .
The purpose not to delete those rows , but instead adding a strikethrough / linethrough to those row.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and show the relevant code.

Comment: post edited
I hope now you don't consider it as a writing service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set up a CSS class for the strikethrough:

```
<style>
.old-row {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>
```

Then, create a variable to know when to apply strikethrough in your loop:

```
$add_strikethrough = '';
if (preg_match('/\bold\b/',$row['Notes']))
    $add_strikethrough = ' old-row':
}
```

Finally, add that class to every row you output:

```
if($i%2==0)
{
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFF00' class='$add_strikethrough'>";
}
else
{
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#99FFCC' class='$add_strikethrough'>";
}
```